# "Число, (не)равное сумме двух предыдущих": писать "не" слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не

"Число, (не)равное сумме двух предыдущих": писать "не" слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом случае *не* пишется раздельно: *число, не равное сумме двух предыдущих*.

Прилагательное *равный* стоит после определяемого слова и имеет зависимое слово, что сближает прилагательное с причастием.

Не с прилагательным пишется раздельно "*иногда при постановке прилагательного с зависимыми словами после определяемого существительного, например: предприятия, не подведомственные тресту (в условиях обособления конструкция с прилагательным приближается по значению к причастному обороту); ср.: шахматист играл в несвойственном ему стиле – черты, не свойственные нашей молодёжи"* [Не с прилагательными](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/67/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8).

Comment: _Прилагательное равный стоит после определяемого слова..._ === По-моему, для **не равный** не имеет значения, **до** или **после** определяемого слова оно стоит. _"(Не)равное сумме двух предыдущих число..."_ -- и здесь, я думаю, Вы выберете раздельное написание.

Comment: Слово  "неравный"  пишется слитно в выражениях типа "неравный брак", "неравный поединок" и др., где оно стоит перед определяемым словом. Именно поэтому я обратила внимание на позицию слова в данном предложении.  Положение после определяемого слова - это одна из причин раздельного написания с не  прилагательного "равный".

Answer (score 1):

> "Число, (не)равное сумме двух предыдущих": писать "не" слитно или
>   раздельно?

Обычно пишут раздельно.

Comment: Есть правило, которым это объясняется?

Comment: "(Не)равный" никогда не пишется слитно, кроме "силы были неравны", "неравный бой" и некоторых других.